# JS: Convert value from textarea into valid JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create a textarea where a user can edit a JSON object to change a programs configuration. This code is run when a user attempts to save the configuration and convert the textarea's value into a JSON object.

```
// Convert the value into a JSON ready string
var rule = JSON.stringify($(this).val());

rule = JSON.parse(rule);

alert(JSON.stringify(rule));

/* The alerted string:
"{\n    \"thing1\": \"\",\n    \"thing2\": [],\n    \"thing3\": [],\n    \"thing4\": [],\n    \"thing5\": [],\n    \"thing6\": false,     \n}"
*/
```

The code completes without throwing any errors but the JSON string created is still filled with newline characters. Trying to access any of the keys, for example alert(rule.thing6); returns nothing instead of false. How do I convert my textarea value into a valid JSON object? I do not need to preserve newline characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.stringify is used to convert a javascript object to a JSON string. The value you get from your textarea will already be a (presumably JSON) string.

So you can skip the stringify step and should just need to parse it.

```
// Convert the value into a JSON ready string
var rule = JSON.parse($(this).val());

alert(JSON.stringify(rule))
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual string doesn't contain a newline character (\n), but an escaped newline character (\n). A newline character would have been rendered as a line break.

To remove those, use `.replace(/\\n/g, '')` like this `(JSON.stringify(rule)).replace(/\\n/g, '')`

Also You have a comma in the end, which makes the json invalid `\"thing6\": false,}"` should be `\"thing6\": false}"`

Comment: That removes the newline characters but the JSON still does not work `"{    \"website\": \"\",    \"tags\": [],    \"ignore_blacklist_tags\": [],    \"blacklist_tags\": [],    \"blacklist_urls\": [],    \"chain\": false,     }"`

Comment: You have a comma in the end, which makes the json invalid
`\"thing6\": false,}"` should be `\"thing6\": false}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Convert the value into a JSON ready string
var rule = JSON.stringify($(this).val());

rule = rule.replace(/\s/g, ""); //add this line

rule = JSON.parse(rule);
alert(JSON.stringify(rule));
```

moreover your json object cannot contain , (comma) after last attribute.

`\"thing6\": false,}"` should be `\"thing6\": false}"` this.

Answer (score 0):

There is **NO** guarantee that **Javascript object as a string** you get from the **Text Area** must a **JSON string** because the JS string may include the formatting details **(\n, \t)** and missing **quotes** for the **keys** in the object.

Solution:

```
const txtAreaStr = "\t\t{ name:'jay', \n\n\n age: 7}\t\t"; // string from text area
const obj = eval("(" + txtAreaStr + ")"); // js obj   => {name: 'jay', age: 7}
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);   // json str => '{"name":"jay","age":7}'
const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString );  // json obj => {name: 'jay', age: 7}
```

**Note:** Be cautious while using eval() because it is hacker's friendy !